# How to display sister pages of current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've one menu with submenu in my site, when i press in one item of submenu i see one page, this page have a left sidebar with list of these submenu pages and highlightning current page that i see.

[image]

[image]

I tryed using `wp_list_pages` but, not work. Can i use `WP_Query`?

How do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to display child pages of your lefthand menu?

Comment: No, they are sisters of the current page, they are in same submenu :)

Comment: So you don't want to show child pages at all, you just want to show pages at that same level? Also, what didn't work when you tried to use wp_list_pages?

Comment: Not a wordpress user myself, but I'm assuming you can get your parent and call getChildren() on that.

Comment: @Ian wp_list_pages displays nothing.

Comment: @kery I'm Wordpress user and i love it :D

Comment: if im not mistaken - your'e trying to list the pages on the same level on your single page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve a list of a Wordpress page's sibling pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322271/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-a-wordpress-pages-sibling-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to display only the siblings of the page you can try this.

```
$parent = $post->post_parent;
wp_list_pages(array(
'depth'=>1, //displays only the top depth
'exclude'=>$parent, //Exclude the parent page from showing up in the list.
));
```

You'll need to create some conditional statements for child pages to display their sibling pages,but this should at least get you going. By specifying which ID to include in the page list it should output a list for you.

Also, you can refer to the [wp_list_pages codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) for detailed description on how it works :)

**EDIT: Tested the above and fixed an element that wasn't working. It should now work to display only the sibling pages**